# Translate string from the database to different languages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, database-schema

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Language Translation for Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864040/language-translation-for-tables)

I'm creating a table in sql server 2008. The schema  of the table:

**Commments**

```
CommentID  int
Category   nvarchar(250)
Comment    nvarchar(250)
```

This table stores the english version for all the comments on the Comments table. Based on these comments, I would like to pull from the database the corresponding Comment for languages like spanish, french, etc.

What is the best way to accomplish my goal? I would like to keep track the translated comment based on my orginal CommentID.

Also, it was suggested for another question to create a column for each language. However, what happens when I would like to add a new language?

[Translate string in different language that is in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876608/translate-string-in-different-language-that-is-in-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to save the comment in the original language and the comment in English, all in the database, I would create the table that you said (CommentID, Category, Comment) with the comment in English and then another table (CommentTranslationID, CommentID, LanguageID, Comment) with a translated version, saving the ISO(2) code for the language

Answer (score 0):

You could have another table that keeps the translated versions...

**CommentsTranslated**

```
Id
CommentId
TranslatedComment
Language
```

When you need to pull the translated comment, you would know the commentId and the language.

This also makes it easy to add another language.